# Influence of the different schools in the way we do math?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I am interested in some reference or book (better an article or a collection of articles, so I don't feel bad if I don't finish a whole book) explaining the diverse lines of thought in mathematics of what constitutes a proof, for example (I know Lakatos' book and only that one). More concretely, if there is anything explaining how the Bourbaki school influenced the European way of seeing Mathematics (I don't know about other ways right now), that would be awesome. Anything would be very interesting to read!

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  Though I must admit, my first reaction was "What diversity?"  Along less pessimistic lines, I would be extremely interested to see a more contemporary account of the old Brouwer & Cantor constructivism/intuitionism/classicism debates and developments.  A lot has happened but I haven't seen the stories told well.

Comment: @user33433 thanks! It is interesting to me as well, and I am also very interested in learning about the philosophical debates that have arisen through mathematics' history. At least for me it has been difficult to find people with whom I could talk and discuss these things (maybe because everything seems to be already done¿?)

Comment: I think that it's definitely not all done... if you look at some of what physicists have been doing with topos theory, I think there is a very compelling case that it is time for some serious philosophical arguments over mathematical foundations.

Answer (score 3):

The two examples that immediately come to mind is the Bourbaki school and the Russian school.  The former emphasizes formal presentation along strictly logical lines (definition, theorem, proof, corollary, that sort of thing) and tends to reduce motivating discussions to a minimum.  The Russian school as I see it (though this is based on purely anecdotal evidence) holds intuitions and ideas to be more important than theorems and proofs; the insight lurking behind the proof is the important thing.  In conformity with this description, my teacher Misha Gromov once remarked that the only person to have benefited from the Bourbaki project is Pierre Deligne, who really enjoyed reading it from cover to cover (presumably he was able to fill in the missing intuitions and motivations through sheer brilliance). As far as the constructivist/classicist debate, you may enjoy a recent paper published in Intellectica; see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5456).

Comment: This is a useful response, and I agree with you. It is interesting that in Spain we are taught using the Bourbaki approach and however the teachers that avoid that line (and manage to be polite in their presentation) are those who get best marks in the surveys from the students (and usually whose students get the best marks in the exams). I also wonder how comes that not much can be said of the German way of teaching and understanding mathematics despite the fact that the region has produced many of the best mathematicians in history.